# Open dialog box to select CSV file twincat 3

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-ads

I am trying to create a recipe handler using arrays and read CSV files, and i am trying from the HMI to create a dialog browser to open a specific folder and then select any `.csv` file and load it to the array, but I can not find ANY information about it. Does anyone have any info if its possible to do?

I have been searching google a lot and I have been trying to convert code from other languages but I can not get it to work.

I have also tried to make a button to open ANY csv file from the folder as well but I can not get that to work either. As of now I have hardcoded the file to open and that works. But in production the file names will change from every file.

I really hope someone have any solution to this

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Recipe Manager Extension](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/te2000_tc3_hmi_engineering/5781889163.html?id=4806481131567006969) for the HMI. This extension allows you to load, edit and save recipes from the HMI. I'm not sure if it saves the data in a CSV file in the background.

If you're really tied to csv files, then you would have to build a custom converter to make it work with the Recipe Manager. See an example on how to read and write CSV files [here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35419787.html?id=8938849443229292945).

Finally there is also the [old recipe manager](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2530462603.html?id=7825910455748267475). This doesn't save the recipes in CSV files, but in a custom `.txtrecipe` format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a step-back from your current view of things and a reframing.

Rather than going through the process of a dialog browser why not just use an array of strings to populate your paths?

Using [FB_EnumFindFileEntry](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/34982539.html&id=5692657966202396328) or [FB_EnumFindFileList](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/34981003.html&id=7414402746647434562) you should be able to find all of the *.csv files inside of a specific folder.
With this information you can populate an array and use the selected item from that array to load a specific recipe.